# How to create an API endpoint to auto generate images and index them to Google?

Tags: rest, google-search, google-image-search

If you [search for "palmeiras x corinthians sofascore"](https://www.google.com/search?q=palmeiras+x+corinthians+sofascore&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjF8ffo4qnzAhXQHLkGHYsPCfYQ_AUoA3oECAEQBQ&cshid=1633110541143649&biw=1024&bih=624), you'll see that SofaScore has:

- 3 different images;
- 3 different aspect ratios;
- all 3 corresponding to the same soccer match.

I have inspected the HTML source code and found this:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/images/share/16x9/palmeiras-corinthians-9540700.png"/>
```

Now, what if I wanna do the same for my website, what should I do:

- simply create an API endpoint?
- create a similar meta tag with my own endpoint?

How do I deal with different aspect ratios?

Comment: What does an "API endpoint" have to do with this?   An API is something that somebody might call on your website.  Don't you just want a server-side script or program that generates images?  I don't see why it should have an API.

Comment: It is an api endpoint, indeed. I have used express to make an endpoint for get requests, which generates an image depending on  given filename id and then sends it in the response. I'll answer the question when I have time.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I have done:

- created an endpoint `images/share/16x9/foo-bar-9540700.jpg`;
- got :filename as a request parameter;
- fetched external API for teams logo, based on id `9540700`;
- used node-canvas to dynamically generate a thumbnail for the match;
- sent generated image in the response to the client;

Regarding Google indexing it: I just had to place the url for the endpoint in a meta tag with `property="og:image"`.

The endpoint url can be placed in `<img>` tags, as well.

---

Useful resources:

- https://flaviocopes.com/canvas-node-generate-image/